# How to find username given uid in Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I'd appreciate if someone could help me out with the fql request.

I tried

```
SELECT username FROM standard_user_info WHERE uid = "100001466426542"
```

which resulted in

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#15) This method must be called with an app access_token.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 15
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using graph API.You will get a JSON response.

http://graph.facebook.com/USERID

For FQL,

SELECT username FROM profile WHERE id = USERID

Answer (score 0):

Verify Permissions and app_access_token.

May be your app donen't set access_token .

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
verify access_token above url and test your FQL.

reference :

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/standard_user_info

The information above has been changed to the link below.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference

Permissions

To read the standard_user_info table you need

an app access_token to get information about any authorized app users

and I found username given uid in facebook using FQL.

> 'query' => "SELECT uid, pic, pic_square, name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = ".$user."
> good luck!